# Adding two random effects within a factor: GAM

Tags: r

From this data:

```
UQdata  MudUQ   Estuary   Site
7.00    10.9    NoriPau   A
6.00    13.9    NoriPau   A
5.00    10.3    NoriPau   B
4.00    7.9     Porirua   A
4.00    8.3     Porirua   A
4.00    8.7     Porirua   A
4.00    10.9    NoriPau   B
3.00    9.8     Porirua   B
3.00    9.8     Porirua   B
3.00    11.5    Porirua   B
```

I'm fitting the below GAM model using the mgcv package:

```
aa2.estuary <- gam(UQdata~s(MudUQ, bs="ps", k=5) + s(Estuary, bs="re"), 
                   family=Gamma(link=log),data=Antho)
```

Problem: I want to add `Estuary` and `Site` within `Estuary` as two random effects (i.e. `s(Estuary ~ Site + Estuary, bs="re")`), but when I try this it throws this error:

```
aa2.estuary <- gam(UQdata ~ s(MudUQ,bs="ps", k=5) + 
                   s(Estuary~Estuary+Site, bs="re"),
                   family=Gamma(link=log),data=Antho)

Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
In addition: Warning message:
In s(Estuary ~ Estuary + Site, bs = "re") :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Any help here will be much appreciated.

---

mnel, I tried your suggest string:

```
> aa1.estuary<-gam(UQdata~s(MudUQ,bs="ps", k=5) + s(Estuary, bs="re") + s(Site, Estuary, bs = 're'),family=binomial, gamma=1,data=Antho)
Error in while (mean(ldxx/(ldxx + ldss)) < 0.4) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example (i.e. some data) -- the example for `bs='re'` from `?gam.vcomp` doesn't suggest that your `s(Estuary~Site+Estuary, bs = 're')` is correct (no mention of a formula interface within a call to `s`). Perhaps `s(Estuary, bs = 're') + s(Site, Estuary, bs = 're')` is what you want

Comment: @mnel I guess that depends on whether `Site:Estuary - 1` is considered  as `Site` *nested* within `Estuary`. `?smooth.construct.re.smooth.spec` has more details. If this isn't considered nested then it may be easier to switch to the **gamm4** package and use it's `gamm()`, which uses `glmer()` to fit the models.

Comment: I've added new information to the above issue

Comment: your last example doesn't use your example data. (and I hope this is just a subset of your data..)

Comment: Amended - its a subset

Comment: your subset is not large enough to run that model (more coefficients than data) -- I think @GavinSimpson is on the more correct track.

Comment: I cannot see that it is documented that the `mgcv::s` function takes a formula argument. This is certainly the first effort I have seen to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By going back to the raw data and renaming `Sites` in association with each estuary (see below):

```
UQdata  MudUQ   Estuary   Site
7.00    10.9    NoriPau   Nori1
6.00    13.9    NoriPau   Nori1
5.00    10.3    NoriPau   Nori2
4.00    7.9     Porirua   Pori1
4.00    8.3     Porirua   Pori1
4.00    8.7     Porirua   Pori1
4.00    10.9    NoriPau   Nori2
3.00    9.8     Porirua   Pori2
3.00    9.8     Porirua   Pori2
3.00    11.5    Porirua   Pori2
```

And including `Site` as another random effect:

```
aa2.estuary <- gam(UQdata ~ s(MudUQ,bs="ps", k=5) + s(Estuary, bs="re") + s(Site, bs="re"),family=Gamma(link=log),data=Antho)
```

And not worrying about which is nested within which. This takes care of both the within `Site` correlations, and the within `Estuary` correlations.